# Unable to install SAP Cloud HANA tools in Eclipse Neon 3

Tags: java, hana, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to install the SAP HANA Tools (https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/neon) in Eclipse Neon 3 using the path **Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software** and adding this link.

Please refer attached screenshots.
[image]

[image]

[image]

When I check the 'SAP HANA Tools' from the list and click on 'Next' button in Eclipse, I get nothing...the Eclipse starts saying **"Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions.."** in the end it fails. This always happens when I'm trying to install tools in Office network.

I believe this is something to do with Proxy in office network. I tried setting the proxy configuration in Eclipse as well like **Eclipse -> Windows -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Action Provider to Manual and HTTP/HTTPS** but still getting the same error.

I can easily install SAP HANA Tools in my personal laptop in home network but not in office network. Please assist to suggest me what could be the root cause as I tried really hard to figure it out but nothing worked. `

Also would like to know in my Eclipse Neon 3 (in office laptop), in proxy entries, `SOCKS` is continued to be checked along with `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. Is this the reason behind it? How can I uncheck `SOCKS` but not `HTTP` & `HTTPS`? I tried unchecking SOCKS but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is behind a proxy and you get this type of error, this is most likely due to the current Eclipse proxy configuration being set to **Direct** in **Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> Active Provider**.

If your proxy is configured at the system level (in the **Windows Setting -> Network & Internet -> Proxy**), then you should be able to set the **Active Provider** to **Native**.

If this still fails, you can set the **Active Provider** to **Manual** and fill the details for each connection type.

When using either **Direct** or **Native**, the entries for HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS will be read only. Only the **Manual** option allows to enter the details for each connection type.

However, as far as I know only HTTP/HTTPS are used by the Eclipse software update feature.

> If you need to get your proxy details, the Chrome browser provide a way to get your current proxy config when accessing the following url: `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` (but there are many alternative options to get the proxy details)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to it. There was some version issue in the plugins so what I did to resolve this issue is by deleting .eclipse folder which is located at c:\users\.**eclipse**.

It resolved my problem.